# New to Kotlin..having issues with Optionals and Casting

Tags: kotlin

Just ver confused about casting and how to set up class variables. In java it was possible to do

```
private var mSectionsStatePageAdapter : SectionsStatePagerAdapter? = null
private val mViewPager : ViewPager? = null
```

now we're in kotlin

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   private var mSectionsStatePageAdapter : SectionsStatePagerAdapter? = null
   private val mViewPager : ViewPager? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val mytoolbar:Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.top_toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(mytoolbar)

    mSectionsStatePageAdapter =  SectionsStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager())
    mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager1)


    setupViewPager(mViewPager)
}



 fun setupViewPager(viewPager :ViewPager):Unit {
        var adapter : SectionsStatePagerAdapter = SectionsStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager())
        adapter.addFragment(Fragment1(),"Fragment1")
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter)
    }
```

I'm getting val can't be reassigned...
Error:(65, 24) Smart cast to 'ViewPager!' is impossible, because 'mViewPager' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time

Answer (score 1):

For Android, it is common to use `lateinit var` because you create the object outside of constructor (in `onCreate`, etc). You can go with two route:

- `lateinit var variable:Type`
- `var variable:Type?`

I would recommend if your variable should be available when you are ready to use it. You do not need to do `null` check. `lateinit` mean late initialization.  Kotlin use `null` to represent not yet initialized, so you cannot use nullable type and assign null on it.

If your variable is nullable, then you should go the second way.

Beside, if you are handling views, you should use [Android extension](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) to do it. You don't need to `findViewById` in `Activity` or `Fragment` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things happening here.

First, as @gyosida points out, you have defined your `mPager` property as `val` instead of `var` so it cannot be reassigned in the line `mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager1)`. As @Joshua points out, you either have to make it a `var` or you need to make it a `lateinit val` to solve the problem of it not being initialised with the class instance.

The second is represented by the actual error you describe of, 'mutable property that could have been changed', and you will continue to see this **if you make it a var.** The approach of using `lateinit` is most likely the better idea.

However, to explain this error, in your method declaration of:

```
fun setupViewPager(viewPager: ViewPager): Unit {
```

you have said that the argument for `viewPager` cannot be null. If it were, it would be `viewPager: ViewPager?`. So, if you pass something that could be null into it, you will get a compile error.

What Kotlin is telling you is that in between the lines:

```
mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager1)
```

and

```
setupViewPager(mViewPager)
```

something - imagine another method on another thread - could potentially have changed the value of `mViewPager` from that assigned instance to null. Therefore it's not safe to pass it in.

The only way to solve this without changing the method is supply a value that is guaranteed to be non-null. There are a few ways you could do that:

- assign your value to a method-level variable that can't be interfered with, and supply that as the argument
- only call your function *if* the value is non-null, e.g. `mViewPager?.let{ pager -> setupViewPager(pager)}`
- assert that `mViewPager` will not be null, leaving any violations to fail at runtime, e.g. `setupViewPager(mViewPager!!)`